# Shiny server on EC2: URL lists folder content instead of displaying app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

[Sorry, newbie here!]

I've just installed R server, shiny server on an ubuntu EC2 instance. I have left the `shiny-server.conf` intact, except that I added: `preserve_logs true;`. The sample app was working fine.

I have removed `/srv/shiny-server/index.html` and `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps`.

I have linked my app files from my /home/myapp directory to `/srv/shiny-server/myapp`. The app files consists of a single `apps.R`, a `footer.html`, and a small dataset `.Rds`, and a `www/style.css` file.

When I navigate to http://[myip]:3838/ the only thing is the directory listing; the only folder is : myapp. When I click to http://[myip]:3838/myapp/ , I see the directory listing as well. That is, I see the content, and I can download each of them. BUt I see no evidence of the app running. If I click on `apps.R`, my browser downloads the file.

PS: the app works fine when tested in Rstudio, or deployed on Shinyapps.io

Answer (score 1):

If anyone from the future reads this, I wish you heard the loud headslap when I realized my app single-file should be called `app.R`, not `apps.R` (which makes a lot of sense in retrospect).